# Amazon: Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Exception Using Xamarin to Upload Image

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, xamarin, amazon-s3

We were using an old SDK for Amazon A3 on a project that I am supporting (lab version). Now I want to update all SDKs from Amazon and use Cognito for authentication on it instead of passing credentials directly as I was doing before.

My application runs on Xamarin android and needs to upload photos to Amazon S3.

Using the AWSSDK I got from the NuGet Package Library on Xamarin Studio, my Code to create AmazonS3Client:

```
var credentials = new CognitoAWSCredentials("my pool id", Amazon.RegionEndpoint.UEast1);

var config = new AmazonS3Config() { RegionEndpoint = Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USWest2, Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30) };

this.s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials, config);
```

My code to upload image with S3 client:

```
var request = new PutObjectRequest();
request.AutoCloseStream = true;
request.BucketName = this.bucket;
request.FilePath = filePath;
request.Key = key;
request.ContentType = "image/jpg";

if (handler != null) 
{
    request.StreamTransferProgress += (object sender, Amazon.Runtime.StreamTransferProgressArgs e) =>
    {
        handler(e, pedidoLacre, key, fotoPlaca);
    };
}

var taskResponse = this.s3Client.PutObjectAsync(request);
Task.WaitAll(taskResponse);

if (taskResponse.Exception != null)
{
    throw taskResponse.Exception;
}
```

Error in Exception:

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---&gt; Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Exception: The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint. ---&gt; Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseException: Exception of type 'Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseException' was thrown.
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RedirectHandler.HandleRedirect (IExecutionContext executionContext) [0x00016] in d:\Jenkins\jobs\v3-stage-release\workspace\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\HttpHandler\_mobile\HttpRequestMessageFactory.cs:183 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RedirectHandler+&lt;InvokeAsync&gt;d__0`1[Amazon.S3.Model.PutObjectResponse].MoveNext () [0x0004b] in d:\Jenkins\jobs\v3-stage-release\workspace\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\HttpHandler\_mobile\HttpRequestMessageFactory.cs:261 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000b] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0004e] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[Amazon.S3.Model.PutObjectResponse].GetResult () [0x00000] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Unmarshaller+&lt;InvokeAsync&gt;d__0`1[Amazon.S3.Model.PutObjectResponse].MoveNext () [0x0005f] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000b] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0004e] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[Amazon.S3.Model.PutObjectResponse].GetResult () [0x00000] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at Amazon.S3.Internal.AmazonS3ResponseHandler+&lt;InvokeAsync&gt;d__0`1[Amazon.S3.Model.PutObjectResponse].MoveNext () [0x0000d] in d:\Jenkins\jobs\v3-stage-release\workspace\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Services\S3\Custom\Internal\AmazonS3ResponseHandler.cs:58 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000b] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0004e] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[Amazon.S3.Model.PutObjectResponse].GetResult () [0x00000] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler+&lt;InvokeAsync&gt;d__1`1[Amazon.S3.Model.PutObjectResponse].MoveNext () [0x00077] in d:\Jenkins\jobs\v3-stage-release\workspace\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\Marshaller.cs:85 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseExceptionHandler.HandleException (IExecutionContext executionContext, Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseException exception) [0x00064] in d:\Jenkins\jobs\v3-stage-release\workspace\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\RedirectHandler.cs:150 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ExceptionHandler`1[Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseException].Handle (IExecutionContext executionContext, System.Exception exception) [0x00007] in d:\Jenkins\jobs\v3-stage-release\workspace\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\RedirectHandler.cs:41 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.ProcessException (IExecutionContext executionContext, System.Exception exception) [0x0000d] in d:\Jenkins\jobs\v3-stage-release\workspace\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\Marshaller.cs:38 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler+&lt;InvokeAsync&gt;d__1`1[Amazon.S3.Model.PutObjectResponse].MoveNext () [0x000b4] in d:\Jenkins\jobs\v3-stage-release\workspace\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\Marshaller.cs:88 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000b] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0004e] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[Amazon.S3.Model.PutObjectResponse].GetResult () [0x00000] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler+&lt;InvokeAsync&gt;d__0`1[Amazon.S3.Model.PutObjectResponse].MoveNext () [0x00066] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000b] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0004e] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[Amazon.S3.Model.PutObjectResponse].GetResult () [0x00000] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CredentialsRetriever+&lt;InvokeAsync&gt;d__0`1[Amazon.S3.Model.PutObjectResponse].MoveNext () [0x000d5] in d:\Jenkins\jobs\v3-stage-release\workspace\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\HttpHandler\HttpHandler.cs:357 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000b] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0004e] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[Amazon.S3.Model.PutObjectResponse].GetResult () [0x00000] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler+&lt;InvokeAsync&gt;d__0`1[Amazon.S3.Model.PutObjectResponse].MoveNext () [0x0003f] in d:\Jenkins\jobs\v3-stage-release\workspace\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Util\AWSSDKUtils.cs:572 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000b] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0004e] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[Amazon.S3.Model.PutObjectResponse].GetResult () [0x00000] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler+&lt;InvokeAsync&gt;d__0`1[Amazon.S3.Model.PutObjectResponse].MoveNext () [0x00066] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000b] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0004e] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[Amazon.S3.Model.PutObjectResponse].GetResult () [0x00000] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler+&lt;InvokeAsync&gt;d__0`1[Amazon.S3.Model.PutObjectResponse].MoveNext () [0x00066] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000b] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0004e] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[Amazon.S3.Model.PutObjectResponse].GetResult () [0x00000] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at Amazon.S3.Internal.AmazonS3ExceptionHandler+&lt;InvokeAsync&gt;d__0`1[Amazon.S3.Model.PutObjectResponse].MoveNext () [0x0001c] in d:\Jenkins\jobs\v3-stage-release\workspace\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Services\S3\Custom\Internal\AmazonS3ExceptionHandler.cs:57 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000b] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0004e] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[Amazon.S3.Model.PutObjectResponse].GetResult () [0x00000] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorCallbackHandler+&lt;InvokeAsync&gt;d__0`1[Amazon.S3.Model.PutObjectResponse].MoveNext () [0x00064] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000b] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0004e] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[Amazon.S3.Model.PutObjectResponse].GetResult () [0x00000] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.MetricsHandler+&lt;InvokeAsync&gt;d__0`1[Amazon.S3.Model.PutObjectResponse].MoveNext () [0x00011] in d:\Jenkins\jobs\v3-stage-release\workspace\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\HttpHandler\_mobile\HttpRequestMessageFactory.cs:130 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WaitAll (System.Threading.Tasks.Task[] tasks, Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00242] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WaitAll (System.Threading.Tasks.Task[] tasks, Int32 millisecondsTimeout) [0x00000] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WaitAll (System.Threading.Tasks.Task[] tasks) [0x00000] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at LacreDigital.Shared.S3.LacreS3.Upload (System.String filePath, System.String key, LacreDigital.Shared.Data.PedidoLacre pedidoLacre, FotoPlaca fotoPlaca, LacreDigital.Shared.S3.HandleUploadProgressEvent handler) [0x00065] in d:\Projetos\LacreMobile\Mobile\branches\_10899\LacreDigital.Shared\Code\S3\LacreS3.cs:69 
---&gt; (Inner Exception #0) Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Exception: The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint. ---&gt; Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseException: Exception of type 'Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseException' was thrown.
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RedirectHandler.HandleRedirect (IExecutionContext executionContext) [0x00016] in d:\Jenkins\jobs\v3-stage-release\workspace\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\HttpHandler\_mobile\HttpRequestMessageFactory.cs:183 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RedirectHandler+&lt;InvokeAsync&gt;d__0`1[Amazon.S3.Model.PutObjectResponse].MoveNext () [0x0004b] in d:\Jenkins\jobs\v3-stage-release\workspace\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\HttpHandler\_mobile\HttpRequestMessageFactory.cs:261 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000b] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0004e] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[Amazon.S3.Model.PutObjectResponse].GetResult () [0x00000] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Unmarshaller+&lt;InvokeAsync&gt;d__0`1[Amazon.S3.Model.PutObjectResponse].MoveNext () [0x0005f] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000b] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0004e] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[Amazon.S3.Model.PutObjectResponse].GetResult () [0x00000] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at Amazon.S3.Internal.AmazonS3ResponseHandler+&lt;InvokeAsync&gt;d__0`1[Amazon.S3.Model.PutObjectResponse].MoveNext () [0x0000d] in d:\Jenkins\jobs\v3-stage-release\workspace\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Services\S3\Custom\Internal\AmazonS3ResponseHandler.cs:58 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000b] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0004e] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[Amazon.S3.Model.PutObjectResponse].GetResult () [0x00000] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler+&lt;InvokeAsync&gt;d__1`1[Amazon.S3.Model.PutObjectResponse].MoveNext () [0x00077] in d:\Jenkins\jobs\v3-stage-release\workspace\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\Marshaller.cs:85 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseExceptionHandler.HandleException (IExecutionContext executionContext, Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseException exception) [0x00064] in d:\Jenkins\jobs\v3-stage-release\workspace\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\RedirectHandler.cs:150 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ExceptionHandler`1[Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseException].Handle (IExecutionContext executionContext, System.Exception exception) [0x00007] in d:\Jenkins\jobs\v3-stage-release\workspace\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\RedirectHandler.cs:41 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.ProcessException (IExecutionContext executionContext, System.Exception exception) [0x0000d] in d:\Jenkins\jobs\v3-stage-release\workspace\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\Marshaller.cs:38 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler+&lt;InvokeAsync&gt;d__1`1[Amazon.S3.Model.PutObjectResponse].MoveNext () [0x000b4] in d:\Jenkins\jobs\v3-stage-release\workspace\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\Marshaller.cs:88 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000b] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0004e] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[Amazon.S3.Model.PutObjectResponse].GetResult () [0x00000] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler+&lt;InvokeAsync&gt;d__0`1[Amazon.S3.Model.PutObjectResponse].MoveNext () [0x00066] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000b] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0004e] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[Amazon.S3.Model.PutObjectResponse].GetResult () [0x00000] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CredentialsRetriever+&lt;InvokeAsync&gt;d__0`1[Amazon.S3.Model.PutObjectResponse].MoveNext () [0x000d5] in d:\Jenkins\jobs\v3-stage-release\workspace\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\HttpHandler\HttpHandler.cs:357 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000b] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0004e] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[Amazon.S3.Model.PutObjectResponse].GetResult () [0x00000] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler+&lt;InvokeAsync&gt;d__0`1[Amazon.S3.Model.PutObjectResponse].MoveNext () [0x0003f] in d:\Jenkins\jobs\v3-stage-release\workspace\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Util\AWSSDKUtils.cs:572 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000b] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0004e] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[Amazon.S3.Model.PutObjectResponse].GetResult () [0x00000] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler+&lt;InvokeAsync&gt;d__0`1[Amazon.S3.Model.PutObjectResponse].MoveNext () [0x00066] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000b] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0004e] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[Amazon.S3.Model.PutObjectResponse].GetResult () [0x00000] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler+&lt;InvokeAsync&gt;d__0`1[Amazon.S3.Model.PutObjectResponse].MoveNext () [0x00066] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000b] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0004e] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[Amazon.S3.Model.PutObjectResponse].GetResult () [0x00000] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at Amazon.S3.Internal.AmazonS3ExceptionHandler+&lt;InvokeAsync&gt;d__0`1[Amazon.S3.Model.PutObjectResponse].MoveNext () [0x0001c] in d:\Jenkins\jobs\v3-stage-release\workspace\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Services\S3\Custom\Internal\AmazonS3ExceptionHandler.cs:57 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000b] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0004e] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[Amazon.S3.Model.PutObjectResponse].GetResult () [0x00000] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorCallbackHandler+&lt;InvokeAsync&gt;d__0`1[Amazon.S3.Model.PutObjectResponse].MoveNext () [0x00064] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000b] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0004e] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0
```

What we think is an important detail here is that our S3 bucket is located in the US-WEST-2 region, whereas the Cognito is located in US-EAST-1. We read about it and it shouldn't be a problem, but you never know.

**EDIT**
We discarted the possibility of the region error, because we created a new bucket on the same region as the S3 client and the Exception remains.

Comment: So your S3 bucket is in US-West-2, and you've established an AmazonS3Client pointing at US-East-1. And it can't find your bucket, because your bucket does not exist in US-East-1. Have you tried pointing your AmazonS3Client at US-West-2?

Comment: Sorry, we posted here an inverted information. Now the code it's updated.

Comment: im trying to do the same thing, did you get this solved in the end?

Comment: I managed to create a Bucket through the code. Created by S3 interface without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A time ago, I find a solution for this problem.

My solution is creating the bucket with code.

```
var response = this.s3Client.PutBucketAsync("example");
```

It is a problem in Amazon S3 using an sdk for xamarin.